# Pivot table with conditions

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Here is my data:

```
DECLARE @TreatmentTableVariables TABLE(ParameterCode VARCHAR(64), Value varchar(64))

INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('SourceCode','NS')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripFirstTravelDate','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('PaxType','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('ChannelID','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('RoleName','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripOriginLocationCode',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripDestinationLocationCode',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('ExternalBookingID',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('NumberOfPassengers',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('FareClass',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripType',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('BookingWeekday','Monday')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripOriginCountryCode',NULL)
```

My VALUE columns goal is to know which variables I will use to pu
and I put these into a table

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ParameterCode, Value
    INTO Staging.tmpParameterCodes
    FROM @TreatmentTableVariables;
SET @ParameterCodesToPivot = (SELECT '['+LEFT(ParameterCode, LEN(ParameterCode) - 2)
                              FROM (
                                        SELECT ParameterCode + '],['
                                        FROM Staging.tmpParameterCodes
                                        FOR XML PATH ('')

                                    ) c (ParameterCode)
IF @ParameterCodesToPivot IS NULL SET @ParameterCodesToPivot='[Empty_TreatmentDW.InputParameter_Table]'
```

Then I pivot these variables based on them existing in another table:

```
SET @sqlquery = '

    SELECT *
    INTO 
    Staging.tmpTreatmentInputParameters
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                tip.TreatmentID,
                tip.ParameterCode,
                tip.ClientCode,
                tip.Value
            FROM AnalyticsDW.TreatmentInputParameter tip
            Where tip.TreatmentID between 1 and 1000
        )p
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(Value)
            FOR ParameterCode IN ( '+ @ParameterCodesToPivot +' )
        ) AS PVT'
```

The goal of the pivot is to get the values of each treatmentID for all the variables in the @ParameterCodesToPivot. I am not sure where to put the condition.

Changing the Pivot table code from

```
SELECT 
            tip.TreatmentID,
            tip.ParameterCode,
            tip.ClientCode,
            tip.Value
        FROM AnalyticsDW.TreatmentInputParameter tip
        Where tip.TreatmentID between 1 and 1000
```

to

```
SELECT 
                tip.TreatmentID,
                tip.ParameterCode,
                tip.ClientCode,
                tip.Value
            FROM AnalyticsDW.TreatmentInputParameter tip
            inner join Staging.tmpParameterCodes TPC
            on tip.ParameterCode=TPC.ParameterCode
            Where tip.TreatmentID between 1 and 1000
            and TPC.Value!=NULL
```

but this makes the puvot table equal null.

if needed i can try and show what my other tables look like, but my code works if I do not put this Value!=NULL part in the where statement. So I am wondering if I am thinking about the conditions wrong.

Edit:
AnalyticsDW.TreatmentInputParameter data looks like

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(
[TreatmentID] varchar(100),
[ParameterCode] VARCHAR(100),
[ClientCode] VARCHAR(100),
[Value] varchar(100)
)
insert into @data values
('7','SourceCode','FR','NS')
```

Comment: Remember that nothing = NULL and nothing is not equal to NULL either. When you have NULL on either side of equality (or inequality) check the results is ALWAYS NULL. The bigger challenge is that without details about the other tables we are pretty much guessing as to what might happen in your queries.

Comment: what @SeanLange is trying to say is you should use `TPC.Value IS NOT NULL` instead of !=   or you can use use `ISNULL(TPC.Value,'') != ''` if you want to eliminate NULL and empty strings

Comment: Thanks @JamieD77. Not sure why it came out so oddly yesterday. :)

Comment: makes sense, looks to be making a difference...thanks for the help